# Qt time zone abbreviation (QTimeZone)

Tags: qt

In the following code, I'm making a string (`QString filename`) from a date (`QDateTime dateTime`):

```
void Recorder::recordFile(QByteArray ba, QDateTime dateTime, QString extension)
{
    QLocale ptbr(QLocale::Portuguese, QLocale::Brazil);
    QString filename = ptbr.toString(dateTime, FORMAT);
    filename.append(extension);

    recordFile(ba, filename);
}
```

Where `const QString Recorder::FORMAT("yyyy MMMM dd@HH.mm.ss zzz ap t");`.

So the result is a filename like `2015 julho 18@23.19.04 678 pm E. South America Standard Time.etm`, where the `E. South America Standard Time` part came from the "t" at the end of the `FORMAT`.

Instead of `E. South America Standard Time`, may I have something short, i.e. `BRT`?

I've tried (without success):

```
QTimeZone timeZone;
QString zone = timeZone.abbreviation(dateTime);
```

Comment: You use invalid `timeZone` object, so you won't get anything correct from it. You should use something like `dateTime.timeZone().abbreviation(dateTime)` or simply `dateTime.timeZoneAbbreviation()`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, I tried both and got the same, `E. South America Standard Time`. Any thing else I can do?